# google meet link not getting added while creating events using google calendar API

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

I am using google calendar API to add events in google calendar,but there is no google meet URL getting attached to the newly created events .what is I am doing wrong here?

this is the POST  API I am using to create events `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events`

request body that I am using

```
{
      "calendarId": "primary",
      "conferenceDataVersion":1,
      "end": {
       "dateTime": "2022-08-12T06:00:00Z",
        "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
      },
      "start": {
        "dateTime": "2022-08-12T06:00:00Z",
        "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
      },
        "conferenceData": {
            "createRequest": {
            "conferenceSolutionKey": {
                "type": "hangoutsMeet"
            },
            "requestId": "fgchvng5"
            },
            "entryPoints": [
                {
                    "entryPointType": "video"
                }
                ]
        },
      "summary": "titles are cool"
      }
```

response I am getting

```
{
    "kind": "calendar#event",
    "etag": "\"3320574101004000\"",
    "id": "d9f87ncse47u7ea7uam1n70bhc",
    "status": "confirmed",
    "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=ZDlmODduY3NlNDd1N2VhN3VhbTFuNzBiaGMgYWtoaWxlbTIwMTdAbQ",
    "created": "2022-08-12T06:50:50.000Z",
    "updated": "2022-08-12T06:50:50.502Z",
    "summary": "titles are cool",
    "creator": {
        "email": "testmail@gmail.com",
        "self": true
    },
    "organizer": {
        "email": "testmail@gmail.com",
        "self": true
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2022-08-12T06:00:00Z",
        "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2022-08-12T06:00:00Z",
        "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
    },
    "iCalUID": "d9f87ncse47u7ea7uam1n70bhc@google.com",
    "sequence": 0,
    "reminders": {
        "useDefault": true
    },
    "eventType": "default"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After trying for hours i found out that need to pass `conferenceDataVersion=1` As a query string in event creation API as follows

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?conferenceDataVersion=1
```

Comment: I was doing same mistake for two days and struggling what was going wrong. I in fact didn't realise the mistake until I came across this post. Thanks much!